# upload image and insert text in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert, image-uploading

im trying to upload an image with a title and description along with the image upload. My image upload and text inputs work separately and the text and the image path is also inserted to the DB but i still cant figure how to combine both

i used the guides given in http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

```
function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
```

can someone tell me how can i insert some text fields along with the image upload form to a sql database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, just put the image upload input in the same form, like:

```
// view
echo form_open_multipart('controller_name/do_upload');
echo form_input("title", "");
echo form_input("description", "");
echo form_upload("userfile");
echo form_close
```

And add in the controller the POST reading:

```
// controller
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    // validate the POST data 
    // http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|required')

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {   
        // failed validation
        $this->load->view('myform');

        // quit here
        return false;
    }

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        // no file uploaded or failed upload
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        // success
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $description = $this->input->post('description');

        // a model that deals with your image data (you have to create this)
        $this->your_upload_model->add($title, $description, $data["file_name"]);

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

You will also need to make a proper model to input the data in the database.

Comment: Hello @Woxxy Nice answer.  but what if the image upload is optional to update. what to do in that scenario?