# Codeigniter 3.1.0 file upload works, but image 'full_path' info never inserted into db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've managed to cobble together a user profile page that outputs all current/relevant `users` table into form text inputs ( via `set_value()`), as well as has a file upload input for the image upload (which is to be displayed to the page upon update). The form upload process is indeed trivial;

**Profile.php (controller file)**

```
function update() //"action" method from submission form 
{
      if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') 
      {
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('website', 'Website');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('avatar', 'Profile Image', 'callback_image_upload');

          $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', 'This %s must have at least %s characters');
          $this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', 'This %s must have at least %s characters');

           if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
           {
              //Get the info from the form
              $website = $this->input->post('website');
              $password = $this->input->post('password');
              $temp = $this->upload->data('full_path');
              $avatar = $temp['file_name']; // to get image file name from upload script to be stored in the database

              //load the model
              $this->load->model('profile_model');
              $this->Profile->updateProfile($id,$avatar,$website, $password);
           }
           else
           {
              redirect('profile', 'refresh');           
           }
     }
}

function image_upload() //callback for previous update function
{ 
  if($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
  {
  if($_FILES['avatar']['size'] != 0)
  {
     $id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id('id');

     $config['upload_path']   = './assets/images/avatars/'; 
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png'; 
     $config['file_name']     = 'avatar_'.substr(md5(rand()),0,7);
     $config['overwrite']     = true; 
     $config['max_size']  = 10400; 

     $this->load->library('upload', $config);
     $this->upload->initialize($config);

      if (!$this->upload->do_upload('avatar'))
      { 
         $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
         $this->load->view('profile_view', $error);  
      }    
      else
      {
         $avatar = $this->upload->data();

         $data = array(
            'path' => $avatar['full_path'],
            'avatar' => $avatar['file_name'],
            'maintain_ratio' => true,
            'width' => 300,
            'height' => 300

         );
         $fname = $avatar['file_name'];
         $fpath=$avatar['full_path'].$fname;

         return $avatar;
      }    
  }    
 }
}
```

I know for a fact, I start to stumble and crash at the end of the 2nd function in regard to having the `$avatar['full_path']` CI data array prototype element insert itself into a db column on my `users` table named `avatar`. Having rewritten the previous two transcribed functions as well as the model;

```
//function to update user_profile    
function updateProfile($id, $avatar, $website, $password)
{
  if($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
  {
    if($_FILES['avatar']['error'] == 0)
    {       
      $avatar = $this->input->post('avatar');
      $website = $this->input->post('website');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');

      $data = array(
          'avatar' => $this->input->post('avatar'),
          'website' => $this->input->post('website'),
          'password' => $this->input->post('password')             
      );
      $this->db->set('avatar', $avatar);
      $this->db->set('website', $website);
      $this->db->set('password', $password);
      $this->db->where('id', $id);
      $this->db->update('users', $data);
      redirect('profile', 'refresh');
      exit;       
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting eyestrain trying to see the **exact** spots trashing the data submission process. Not using `$this->db->insert()` as I need to allow users to update their website, password, and profile image. Toyed with the ideas of both replace and insert, and a native PHP approach to the matter;

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
   echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
    echo "File: ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]." Uploaded in:".$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], 
$image_path. $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$full_image_path = '/images/'.$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']; 
$sql="insert into table_name(image) values( '$full_image_path')";
```

but this is one of those times when going native propagates less-than-desirable effects. Every issue related to mine that I examined either left me questioning where the variable values were coming from/going to, or trying for an alternate approach that sacrificed the already-functional upload mechanism in place. Curiously, I even managed to nail down something I thought would be harder;

```
<div class="row">
      <!-- left column -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="text-center">
        <?php
        if(isset($user->avatar)){ // if the avatar has been uploaded then display it ?>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/images/avatars/'.$user->avatar; ?>" class="avatar img-circle" alt="Profile Image" width="300px">
        <?php } else { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/images/avatars/default.jpg'; ?>" class="avatar img-circle" alt="Profile Image" width="300px">                       
        <?php } ?>      
          <?php echo '<h3 class="text-info">'.$user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name.'</h3>.'; ?>
          <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>
          <input id="avatar" name="avatar" type="file" class="form-control" /><br>
        </div>
      </div>
```

getting the profile image to display a `default.jpg` in the case of no user avatar for a new recruit;

[image: User Profile Edit Page]

Of course, if I can't let the users alter those (limited) details, then what good is the profile edit suite (lol!)? After about 9 hours (concurrently), I feel the need to call another pair of eyes on this.

**IN-POST UPDATE**

Even tried to use the code set out in [upload image and insert text in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196195/upload-image-and-insert-text-in-codeigniter), as it looked like maybe it was the callback that was screwing things up. My result was that I was able to change the text inputs (which didn't register a change when I refreshed the PHPMyAdmin view (?!?)), but I lost the upload ability. Spent the last 45 minutes trying to code and post simultaneously (lol!). Will be trying to integrate both approaches ardently after posting this. **Thanks again to anyone who can see what I'm tripping on...**

**UPDATE 2: It Just Gets Stranger...**

So, I rework the single code block (`profile/update`) and check the CI PostData results straight from the Profiler, and I **still** don't have any table updates although I'm shown this;
[image: Current CI Profiler Output]

Even though the Profiler output indicates that uploaded image is in the `tmp` directory of my WAMP solution, browsing there comes up with a big, fat goose egg (unless the upload was corrupted somehow - don't see any evidence if this, though). My next move is to throw `realpath` or `APPPATH` (or a combo of both) on the `$config['upload_path']` just to see if that shakes something loose. As for the text inputs, I haven't been willing to touch `password` until I see both other elements insert themselves 1st. Currently, still trying to figure how to integrate my two separate functions into a single code block. That's the plateau I'm on ATM...along with a (trivial) problem of the `created_on` column auto-updating itself to the current datetime rather than when the user was actually created on. Mayhap be a consequence of my method of translating the Unix-time lodged in that column - but it pales next to the jam I'm trying to flatten.

**Sometimes, The More I Try...**

I so would love the linked solution I provided previously to work, that I'm seeing double-red ATM (lol!). I've gone through a number of permutations on a run at flattening this issue that I've come under a bunch of new ones. I'm not really sure that any other scheme other than using the `callback_image_upload` chained-submission process (especially as I'm now feeling like the linked solution was for a CI 2.x install). It's just stultifying that documentation-sanctioned coding;

```
$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
$this->load->view('profile_view', $error);

     OR

$data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
$this->load->view('profile_view', $data);

    BOTH == 0
```

And it's just a tedious affair the level of permutation that barely escapes being a disciplined version of code flail;

```
function update() //solid code block - 1st attempt
{
   if($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
   {
      if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') 
      {
          $this->load->library('form_validation');

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('website', 'Website', 'trim');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');

          $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', 'This %s must have at least %s characters');
          $this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', 'This %s must have at least %s characters');

           if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
           {
              // failed validation? return to submit form page
              $this->load->view('profile_view');

              // quit here
              return false;
           }
           else
           {
              if($_FILES['avatar']['size'] != 0)
              {
                 $id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id('id');
                 $config['upload_path']   = './assets/images/avatars/'; 
                 $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png'; 
                 $config['file_name']     = 'avatar_'.substr(md5(rand()),0,7);
                 $config['overwrite']     = true; 
                 $config['max_size']  = 10400; 

                 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                 $this->upload->initialize($config);            
              }
           }

           if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('avatar'))
           {
              // no file uploaded or failed upload
              $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
              $this->load->view('profile_view', $error);
           }
           else
           {
              // success
              $avatar = $this->upload->data('full_path');
              $website = $this->input->post('website');
              $password = $this->input->post('password');

              // a model that deals with your image data (you have to create this)
              $this->Profile->updateProfile($id, $website, $password, $avatar);
           }                 
      }

   }
}

===========================================================================  

function do_upload() //solid code block - 2nd attempt
{
  if($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
  {
     // validate the POST data
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('website', 'Website', 'trim');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');

     $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', 'This %s must have at least %s characters');
     $this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', 'This %s must have at least %s characters');

       if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
       {   
          // failed validation
          $this->load->view('profile_view');

          // quit here
          return false;
       }

       $config['upload_path']   = './assets/images/avatars/'; 
       $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png'; 
       $config['file_name']     = 'avatar_'.substr(md5(rand()),0,7);
       $config['overwrite']     = true; 
       $config['max_size']  = 10400; 

       $this->load->library('upload', $config);
       $this->upload->initialize($config);

       if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('avatar'))
       {
           // no file uploaded or failed upload
          $data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
          $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
}
else
{
    // success
    $avatar = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $website = $this->input->post('website');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    // a model that deals with your image data (you have to create this)
    $this->Profile->updateProfile($website, $password, $avatar['full_path']);

    $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
}}}  

==========================================================================  

  // view
  echo form_open_multipart('update/do_upload');
  echo form_input('website', '');
  echo form_input('password', '');
  echo form_upload('avatar');
  echo form_close


   // controller
   function do_upload()
   {
  $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['max_size'] = '100';
  $config['max_width']  = '1024';
  $config['max_height']  = '768';

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  // validate the POST data
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('website', 'Website', 'trim|required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required')

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {   
    // failed validation
    $this->load->view('profile_view');
    return false;
   }

   if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('avatar'))
   {
    // no file uploaded or failed upload
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('profile_view', $error);
   }
   else
   {
    // success
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $website = $this->input->post('website');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    // a model that deals with your image data
    $this->your_upload_model->add($website, $password, $data["file_name"]);

    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }}
```

You get the picture...most pathetically irksome cast in light of the fact that all of those transcribed attempts all pass PostData in the Profiler output, but I get no avatar in the designated folder and no update of the db columns from the model. I may just have to find a suitable replacement for this insanity and dead this avenue altogether. This experience is actually illuminative of the fact that most of the "user dashboard" scripts I've seen all over GitHub and Sourceforge had no combo of image upload and data insertion for a potential member. I'm giving this another few hours until Midnight, then I'm flushing this.

**Rescued From The Crapper...Actually ALMOST there...**
Left out the form validation until I can get this last part functional;

```
function update()
{
    if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in() && $this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') 
    {
        $avatar = array();

        $this->upload->initialize(array(
           'upload_path' => 'assets/images/avatars/',
           'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
           'file_name' => $_FILES['avatar']['name'],
           'overwrite' => TRUE,
           'max_size' => 10400,
        ));

         if ($this->upload->do_upload('avatar'))
         {
             if($_FILES['avatar']['error'] == 0)
             {
                $id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id('id'); 
                $avatar = 'assets/images/avatars/' . $this->upload->data('file_name');
                $website = $this->input->post('website');
                $password = $this->input->post('password');

                 $data = array(
                     'avatar' => $avatar,
                     'website' => $website,
                     'password' => $password               
                 );
                 $this->db->set('avatar', $avatar);
                 $this->db->set('website', $website);
                 $this->db->set('password', $password);
                 $this->db->where('id', $id);
                 $this->ion_auth->update('users', $data);
                 redirect('profile', 'refresh');

             }
         }
         else
             {
                 // no file uploaded or failed upload
                 $this->load->view('edit_profile_view');                   
             }
     }
 }
```

I get the avatar uploaded to my target folder and the path info inserted into the db, but the image won't display on the target pages. To access the uploaded image, I'm using;

```
<?php
 $user->avatar = !empty($this->upload->data('avatar')) ? $this->upload->data('avatar') : 'default.jpg';
?>
<img height="300px" width="300px" class="avatar img-circle" src="<?php echo base_url().$user->avatar.$this->upload->data('file_name'); ?>">
```

I'm not even getting the broken image symbol, just a blank space where the image should be. This is the last of my issues with this process. I'm able to repeatedly upload the avatar to the target folder and insert the path information (which is going to a column in the database named `avatar`);

[image: db table view]

Having the damnedest time trying to access the avatar while using `ion_auth` as the target element id `$user->avatar` and I can't find anything in the `Ion_Auth` docs for this situation as there is nothing dealt with about images and profile pages there. Even trying to follow a tutorial by **Avenir**, gets me completely lost in the outback. I could use some other eyes as I'm on the knife edge and just barely hanging on trying to resolve this. I'm only a millimeter away from my solution and it's pitch-black all around (lol!). **Can I get just a clue...someone...anyone...?**

**More Fun With Documentation...**

Even though the doc on the `HTML Helper` - https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img - was a real interesting eye-opener, I'm still stymied by my inability to use a conditional display device to either display an avatar if there is a path/file entry under the column `avatar`, or just display the `default.jpg` file already uploaded to the target folder path. I'm trying to do it as elegantly as possible (i.e. with the least amount of code), but it's only coming down to two approaches;

```
  <?php
  // if the avatar has been uploaded then display it 
  if(isset($user->avatar))
  { 
  ?>
  <img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/images/avatars/'.$user->avatar; ?>" class="avatar img-circle" alt="Profile Image" width="300px">
  <?php
  }
  else 
  { 
  ?>
   <img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/images/avatars/default.jpg'; ?>" class="avatar img-circle" alt="Profile Image" width="300px">            
  <?php 
  } 
  ?>
```

OR, extrapolated straight from [display default image if user have no photo codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527461/display-default-image-if-user-have-no-photo-codeigniter);

```
<?php
$user->avatar = !empty($this->upload->data('avatar')) ? $this->upload->data('avatar') : 'default.jpg';
?>
<img height="300px" width="300px" class="avatar img-circle" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/images/avatars/'.$user->avatar; ?>">
```

but, I'm only ever getting the `default.jpg` file, and not the appropriate user avatar that's been successfully loaded into the target folder and whose path is successfully inserted in the `avatar` column. :sigh: Gonna  be a long night...

**NEXT-TO-LAST-UPDATE**

Thank you @DFriend for your measured feedback on the previously-discussed issue. The difficulties I'm having are more to do with how I'm using `Ion Auth` as my secondary security blanket. The `default.jpg` idea that you imparted was similar to some of the `$data[]` gymnastics I had to resort to in bringing four different table results into the corresponding controller view page;

```
//Controller
$data['resultset1'] = $this->model1->getAll($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

//View
echo '<div class="scroll" style="width:100%;height:450px;">';
if (!empty($resultset1) && isset($resultset1) && count($resultset1) > 0)
{ 
   foreach ($resultset1 as $data)
   {
  echo '<h4><a title="Click Here For Content" href="'?><?php echo base_url().'articlelist/view/'.$data['article_id'].'">'. htmlspecialchars($data['title']). '</a><br>Category:&nbsp;'.htmlspecialchars($data['category']).'<br>Publisher:&nbsp;'.htmlspecialchars($data['username']).'<br>Published:&nbsp;'.$data['date'].'</h4><hr>';
   } 
 } 
 else
 { 
    echo '<p><font face="arial black" size="5" color="#0000CC">No Articles.</font></p>';
 }
 echo '</div>';
```

Thank you profusely **again** @DFriend, but I'll probably shelve this approach for a later re-examination since I'm principally-concerned with getting the app on the road as all other cylinders are firing as ruthlessly-tested to for the last 2 days. I'm really sure I'm going to just trip over something that helps me achieve my stated goals within the scope of this question. Distressing, but I need a break from this so I can approach it with new eyes and close this question out. This is **definitely** not over (lol!)...I'm just read-drunk at this point.  Thanks also due to all casting eyes upon this issue as well.

Comment: can you `echo` the value of `var_dump($sql)` and post result here

Comment: Sorry, @Albert Akki - I see where you're getting the `$sql` from, but I chose not to go with the native PHP approach since it was wrecking my (current) flow.

Comment: just wanted to show the query by `echo $sql` if possible

Comment: I might see what needs to be done. But before I pursue it I've one question. Is the avatar file required?

Comment: @DFriend - it most certainly is needed (lol!). I would **SO** love it if you could see something I couldn't. Thanks in advance for any awesome pointers you could reference me. I've worked inch-by-inch with the CI 3.1.0 docs to get at least this lost (lol)!.

Comment: And in the previous code referenced in my initial post, I'm able to get the avatar file uploaded to the folder again, and again, and again, and again. It's just that the form update info never makes it to the database and I get no PostData feedback while using the Output Profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is what satisfactory resolution of the issue looks like;**

```
function update()
{
if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in() && $this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') 
{
    $avatar = array();

    $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    $_FILES['avatar']['name'] = $user->avatar;

    // File upload script
    $this->upload->initialize(array(
       'upload_path' => 'assets/images/avatars/',
       'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
       'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
       'max_width' => 300,
       'max_height' => 300,
       'encrypt_name' => TRUE,
       'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
       'xss_clean' => TRUE,
       'file_name' => $_FILES['avatar']['name'],
       'overwrite' => TRUE,
       'max_size' => 10400,
    ));

    // validate the POST data
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('avatar', 'Profile Picture', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('skype', 'Skype', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('twitter', 'Twitter', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('googleplus', 'Googleplus', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('youtube', 'YouTube', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('vimeo', 'Vimeo', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('website', 'Website', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('career', 'Career', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', 'Company', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|min_length[6]|max_length[32]');

    $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', 'This %s must have at least %s characters');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', 'This %s must have at least %s characters');

     if ($this->upload->do_upload('avatar'))
     {
         if($_FILES['avatar']['error'] == 0)
         {
            $id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id('id'); 
            $avatar = $this->upload->data('file_name');
            $mobile = $this->input->post('mobile', true);
            $skype = $this->input->post('skype', true);
            $twitter = $this->input->post('twitter', true);
            $googleplus = $this->input->post('googleplus', true);
            $youtube = $this->input->post('youtube', true);
            $vimeo = $this->input->post('vimeo', true);
            $website = $this->input->post('website', true);
            $career = $this->input->post('career', true);
            $company = $this->input->post('company', true);
            $password = $this->input->post('password', true);   

             $data = array(
                 'avatar' => $avatar,
                 'mobile' => $mobile,
                 'skype' => $skype,
                 'googleplus' => $googleplus,
                 'youtube' => $youtube,
                 'vimeo' => $vimeo,
                 'website' => $website,
                 'career' => $career,
                 'company' => $company,
                 'password' => $password               
             );

               $this->db->set('avatar', $avatar);
               $this->db->set('mobile', $mobile);
               $this->db->set('skype', $skype);
               $this->db->set('googleplus', $googleplus);
               $this->db->set('youtube', $youtube);
               $this->db->set('vimeo', $vimeo);
               $this->db->set('website', $website);
               $this->db->set('career', $career);
               $this->db->set('company', $company);
               $this->db->set('password', $password);
               $this->db->where('id', $id);
               $this->ion_auth->update($user->id, $data);
               redirect('profile', 'refresh');
         }
     }
     else
     {
        // no file uploaded or failed upload
        $this->load->view('edit_profile_view');                   
     }
   }
}
```

I just couldn't let go (lol!). Why would I be a good developer if I couldn't give potential users the benefits of some local link juice and their attractive avatar on the same page;

[image: Success imagery]

I want to publicly thank **@DFriend** once again as I feel they have a way of phrasing answers that force you to confront unconsidered aspects of any problem you're facing (**specifically: my little avatar debacle**);

```
<?php
if (empty($user->avatar)){          
?>
<img height="300px" width="300px" class="avatar img-circle" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/images/avatars/default.jpg'; ?>">
<?php } else {?>            
<img height="300px" width="300px" class="avatar img-circle" src="<?php echo base_url(). 'assets/images/avatars/' . $user->avatar; ?>">  
<?php } ?>
```

With this resolution, I now have a fully functional, basic publishing application that completes a mission I started going on almost eleven months ago. Thanks to anyone who stumbled across this or was in an identical situation and you were able to take something away from my issue. **Inebriation process initialization (lol!)...**

Comment: I'm disappointed that I nulled the `profile_model` to deal with this issue, but it had to be resolved for my own personal peace of mind. I can always restructure the code to shunt the processing off to the model, but I'll be carefully considering this answers' replacement. Will post back on the occasion I have this issue confronted and resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that the avatar is not required. So, I'm not using a field validation callback.

**controller**

```
function update() //"action" method from submission form 
{
    if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
    {
        //no rules on the next one so what's the point?         
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('website', 'Website');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');

        $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', 'This %s must have at least %s characters');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', 'This %s must have at least %s characters');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id('id'); //$id will be NULL if not logged in   

            //Get the info from the form
            $website = $this->input->post('website');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $is_avatar = $this->image_upload();
            if(is_string($is_avatar))
            {
                $this->load->view('profile_view', ['error' => $is_avatar]);
            }
            elseif($is_avatar === TRUE)
            {
                // to get image file name from upload script to be stored in the database
                $avatar = $this->upload->data('file_name');

                //use the next line if you want the full path instead of just the name
                //$avatar = $this->upload->data('full_path');
            }
            else
            {
                $avatar = NULL;
            }

            $this->load->model('profile_model');
            $this->profile_model->updateProfile($id, $avatar, $website, $password);
        }
        else //validation failed
        {
            //if you do this you loose the form_validation errors
            redirect('profile', 'refresh');
            //what you maybe want instead is something like
            //$this->load->view('profile_view'); //if that is where the form you just processed is
        }
    }
    //Not a POST call - go to profile page
    redirect('profile', 'refresh');
}

/**
 * Does the file upload
 * Returns NULL, boolean or string 
 *    NULL if no file posted, 
 *    TRUE if upload worked, 
 *    string if error
 */
function image_upload() //callback for previous update function
{
    if($_FILES['avatar']['size'] === 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['file_name'] = 'avatar_'.substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);
    $config['overwrite'] = true; //will never happen because of previous setting
    $config['max_size'] = 10400;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    //you already initializd the library by passing $config in the previous line
    //$this->upload->initialize($config);

    $is_uploaded = $this->upload->do_upload('avatar');

    if(!$is_uploaded)
    {
        return $this->upload->display_errors();
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

**Model**

Answer the insert or update question by looking for `$id`. If it isn't set then we have a new user to `insert`. If `$id` is set then the user exists, do an `update`

```
//function to update user_profile    
function updateProfile($id, $avatar = NULL, $website = NULL, $password = NULL)
{
    if(isset($avatar))
    {
        $this->db->set('avatar', $avatar);
    }

    if(isset($website))
    {
        $this->db->set('website', $website);
    }

    if(isset($password))
    {
        $this->db->set('password', $password);
    }

    //$id will  be set if logged in. 
    if(isset($id))
    {
        return $this->db
                        ->where('id', $id)
                        ->update('users');
    }

    //Not logged in - add new user with insert
    //make an insert and if it returns true the return the new id of inserted record, else return false
    return $this->db->insert('users') ? $this->db->insert_id() : FALSE;
    //but what you probably really want to do is create a new user via ion_auth. Right?
}
```

**In response to the avatar or default image issue**

Correct me if I'm wrong but `$user->avatar` has the value of the `avatar` field in the `users` table - right? If that is correct, then it seems to me the easiest thing to do is *always store something* in the `avatar` field.

For instance, when the user is first created you store the avatar they provide and if they don't provide one you store default.jpg. Likewise with profile updates - if they provide an image then store it, otherwise leave the field remain as is - default.jpg. Using this approach you know that the table will always provide something to display. Therefore, no further logic is required.

Below are a couple was to actually show the image for your consideration. But first, one comment on code in your question. You show this line of code.

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/images/avatars/'.$user->avatar; ?>" class="avatar img-circle" alt="Profile Image" width="300px">
```

If`$user->avatar` contains the string 'assets/images/avatars/LeeDavis.jpg' then  you have provided the path twice and the resulting HTML would be along these lines.

```
<img src="http://example.com/assets/images/avatars/assets/images/avatars/LeeDavis.jpg" ...and the rest... />
```

As you can see `/assets/images/avatars` is in the `src` string twice.

OK. On to actually showing the image.

Assuming you pass the `$user` object to the view

```
 <img src="<?php echo base_url($user->avatar); ?>" class="avatar img-circle" alt="Profile Image" width="300px">
```

Or if using the HTML Helper you could do this in the controller that displays the profile

```
//assuming that $data is being used to send pass variables to the view
$data['avatar_properties'] = array(
        'src'   => $user->avatar,
        'alt'   => "Profile Image",
        'class' => "avatar img-circle",
        'width' => '300',
);
```

And then in the view file

```
<?php echo img($avatar_properties); />
```

Comment: thank you **SO MUCH** for this thorough dissection - still customizing and fitting. Just need to know: in the profile_view page, I can still put in the $error variable - correct?

Comment: Yes, you can. It is used that way once in the above.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you on this - totally appreciate your efforts (just passed out cold, lol!). I had a play about with the suggested code and there was no PostData returned or avatar uploaded. I'm still in the process of examining repositioning with your provided help, but I have a feeling I'm going to have to suck it up and move on (really **hating** that option). I'll get back to you with the results and then close out this question. Thanks for all your help once again, @DFriend.

Comment: In case you did not notice, I set the upload directory to one on my system - `$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';` which is different from your setup.

Comment: I did indeed, @DFriend - I just customized the `$config['upload_path']` to point to where I was keeping my upload folder. Thank you again for all your assistance. I'm disappointed that I'm not able to pull of both actions in one code block. I'm still digesting what you've provided for me...

Comment: The code/logic in `image_upload()` could easily be moved into the `update()` method. I was lazy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126860/discussion-between-homeoffice-and-dfriend).